# Ionic 3 App launcher icon notifications not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I.m used Ionic 3 and I’m trying to change app launcher icon in a my university project currently I’m working on. I’m following the below [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/badge/) from the ionic docs. But the badge is not showing. anyone know how to do it correctly

```
cordova.plugins.notification.badge.set(10);
```

Comment: Post your code - what have you tried?

Comment: @Stevangelista Sir ,  Updated

Comment: got any solution?

Comment: @HardikMandankaa Sir, its not working. do you know any solution?

Comment: I haven't any solution. I tried much, but not got succeeded

Comment: @HardikMandankaa yes,  https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-badge That implement is not working , I asked for the git but they guys not provided any solutions

Comment: I also create issue https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-badge/issues/124. But no solution.